# Adding CSS to only part of HTML (Login Page)

Tags: html, wordpress, computer-science

I am trying to add a login form on the main page of my Wordpress website right on top of a parallax image (essentially floating).

I have grabbed some HTML and CSS code here:
http://codepen.io/JGoldz75/pen/grRkJK

HTML:

```
<div class="login-page-codepen">
<div class="form-codepen">
<form class="register-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
  <input type="Password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
  <button>create</button>
  <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
</form>
<form class="login-form-codepen">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="Password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <button>login</button>
  <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

    .login-page-codepen {
      width: 360px;
      padding: 8% 0 0;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .form-codepen {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      max-width: 360px;
      margin: 0 auto 100px;
      padding: 45px;
      text-align: center;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    }
    .form-codepen input {
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      outline: 0;
      background: #f2f2f2;
      width: 100%;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0 0 15px;
      padding: 15px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .form-codepen button {
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      outline: 0;
      background: #4CAF50;
      width: 100%;
      border: 0;
      padding: 15px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 14px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
      transition: all 0.3 ease;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .form-codepen button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
      background: #43A047;
    }
    .form-codepen .message {
      margin: 15px 0 0;
      color: #b3b3b3;
      font-

size: 12px;
}
.form-codepen .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form-codepen .register-form {
  display: none;
}
```

The HTML gets added to the website correctly, however the CSS seems to keep applying the container to the whole page which does two things:
1.) Skips formatting what I actually need it to format
2.) Makes the whole website look awful with all texts in two inch margins.

I assume this has got to be a dumb syntax error. This is my first time ever using HTML OR CSS - hence the noobiness. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Here is the test website that I am trying to add this too. I would want this login page to appear right under where it says "TBD" in the background parallax photo: http://nameistbd.co.nf/

Comment: this does not relate to the q, but ur website design is actually amazingly great!

Comment: Well I appreciate that! Once I can figure out how to get this floating login box, I will be happy with the site